# Valac incompatible libX11

Tags: gcc, linker, gtk, vala

For a vala file 'a.vala' using gtk:

```
$ valac a.vala --pkg gtk+-3.0
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libX11.so when searching for -lX11
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/../../../libX11.so when searching for -lX11
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //lib/libX11.so when searching for -lX11
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libX11.so when searching for -lX11
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libpthread.so when searching for -lpthread
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: cc exited with status 256
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

However, the following works..

```
$ valac a.vala --pkg gtk+-3.0 -C
$ gcc a.c `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

Tried removing/installing `glibc-devel.x86_64` and/or `glibc-devel.i686` with no use.

I'm not sure if this can help but it worth mentioning that I used to use vala normally on Fedora 26 and this problem appeared after installing a fresh Fedora 27.

Comment: You might also want to try libX11-devel.x86_64 and libX11-devel.i686, since this is the library the linker can't find.

Comment: It's also worth it to use a build tool like `meson` once you have more dependencies.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff That's actually the answer! Thank you!